# Dart FFI fails loading dynamic library in MacOS

Tags: dart, macos-mojave, flutter-desktop

I am trying to build flutter desktop application in **MacOS** and trying call **C++** code using **dart FFI**. I have used this GitHub project as template and change some source code to call **C++** library. I am able to run this project if I do not use **FFI**.

https://github.com/google/flutter-desktop-embedding

**ERROR :**

> flutter: ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
>   flutter: The following ArgumentError was thrown building MyHomePage(dirty, state: _MyHomePageState#86c2f):
>   flutter: Invalid argument(s): Failed to load dynamic library (dlopen(/usr/lib/structs.dylib, 1): image not
>   flutter: found)
>   flutter:
>   flutter: The relevant error-causing widget was:
>   flutter: MyHomePage
>   flutter: file:///Users/rmazumder/VisualCode-Workspace/flutter-desktop-embedding-master/example/lib/main.dart:39:13
>   flutter:
>   flutter: When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:

**My Flutter and Dart version:**

```
rmazumder$ flutter --version
Flutter 1.12.15-pre.12 • channel master • 
https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision b2a36ffcd2 (22 hours ago) • 2019-11-26 11:45:51 -0500
Engine • revision e136d637a8
Tools • Dart 2.7.0
```

Comment: How exactly did you configure the FFI? It's hard to debug without knowing what changes you've made. It looks like you may be trying to load a library from an absolute path rather than bundling it though, which is problematic if you haven't turned off sandboxing.

Comment: See https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/38314